# How can restore the bottom panel instead of turning off and truning on the power in the special case?

Tags: lxde, panel

When you run lxde as your desktop,accidentally deleted the bottom panel,restore it entering lxterminal:

```
$ rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel
$ lxpanelctl restart
```

My issue is more complicated than that.
I want to add weather plugin in the bottom panel:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I enter `shanghai` to search ,it is always searching!

[image]
End the process!
[image]
The bottom panel disappear after ending the process!
[image]

`ctrl+alt+t` can't call my lxterminal!I have never set hotkey binding with `lxterminal` in `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`!I have to turn off and turn on the power in order to use my pc as normal!

How can restore the bottom panel instead of turning off and truning on the power in my case?